# Python how to define a function that only accepts an integer input that can be used for multiple lines

Tags: function, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that has a user input numbers into multiple different lines of code and I am trying to make it so that if the user inputs something other than a number the program will ask the user again to input the number correctly. I was trying to define a function that I could use for all of them but every time I run the program, it crashes. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

My code:

```
def error():
    global m1
    global m2
    global w1
    global w2
    while True:
        try:
            int(m1 or m2 or w1 or w2)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                float(m1 or m2 or w1 or w2)
            except ValueError:
                m1 or m2 or w1 or w2=input("please input your response correctly...")
                break

m1=input("\nWhat was your first marking period percentage?")
error()
w1=input("\nWhat is the weighting of the first marking period? (in decimal)")
error()
m2=input("\nWhat was your second marking period percentage?")
error()
w2=input("\nWhat is the weighting of the second marking period? (in decimal)")
error()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def user_input(msg):
    inp = input(msg)
    try:
        return int(inp) if inp.isnumeric() else float(inp)
    except ValueError as e:
        return user_input("Please enter a numeric value")


m1=user_input("\nWhat was your first marking period percentage?")
w1=user_input("\nWhat is the weighting of the first marking period? (in decimal)")
m2=user_input("\nWhat was your second marking period percentage?")
w2=user_input("\nWhat is the weighting of the second marking period? (in decimal)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write your function to get one number at a time. If at exception is triggered somewhere, it should be handled. Note how the `get_number` function shown below will keep asking for a number but also shows the prompt specified by its caller. If you are not running Python 3.6 or higher, you will need to comment out the call to `print` in the `main` function.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    p1 = get_number('What is your 1st marking period percentage? ')
    w1 = get_number('What is the weighting of the 1st marking period? ')
    p2 = get_number('What is your 2nd marking period percentage? ')
    w2 = get_number('What is the weighting of the 2nd marking period? ')
    score = calculate_score((p1, p2), (w1, w2))
    print(f'Your score is {score:.2f}%.')


def get_number(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            text = input(prompt)
        except EOFError:
            raise SystemExit()
        else:
            try:
                number = float(text)
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter a number.')
            else:
                break
    return number


def calculate_score(percentages, weights):
    if len(percentages) != len(weights):
        raise ValueError('percentages and weights must have same length')
    return sum(p * w for p, w in zip(percentages, weights)) / sum(weights)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am unable to access the local variables inside of the main function. I am trying to use them (p1,w1,p2,w2) later on and I am unable to recall upon them since they are locally defined inside of the def() main function

Comment: Have you thought about passing the local variables to the functions you are calling later on by providing them as arguments to those functions?

Answer (score 0):

By the following code you can able to make a function that only accept integer value:

```
 def input_type(a):
      if(type(10)==type(a)):
        print("integer")
      else:
        print("not integer")
 a=int(input())
 input_type(a)
```

Comment: Some of us would be grateful if you would remove the leading spaces and use consistent indenting for quicker copy/pasta. I would have edited instead of commenting, but, SO says "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later."